# Can you help me calculate a limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

Is there a way to accurately calculate
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{3 + x} - \sqrt{3 - x}}{\sqrt{4+x^2} - \sqrt{4-2x}}
$$
using brute force with a graphing calculator? I can't use L'Hôpital's rule and based on Wolfram Alpha's calculations, I'm doing it all wrong. It looks like I can't get an accurate form without it, so I just need a decimal. I would really appreciate it if there was some kind of explanation. I don't know anyone to go to that understands calculus, and I really want to understand it.

Comment: Sorry the equation is a mess, I can't find a way to change it!

Comment: Why can you use brute force but not L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: Andre Nicolas- I got a decimal and actual solution on wolfram alpha, are you sure it doesn't exist? I'm seriously confused. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%28sqrt%283%2Bx%29-sqrt%283-x%29%29%2F%28%28sqrt%284%2Bx%5E2%29-sqrt%284-2x%29%29%29%2C+x%3D0

Comment: dfeuer-I'm not that far in calculus yet...

Comment: Brute force might involve putting small values of $x$ into the expression (positive and negative) and observing what is happening (close to 1.1547 until rounding errors occur).  But it is not proof.

Comment: @MiaCcio: My comment was premature, the answer is below. Same method.

Comment: The Maple code $$with(Student[Calculus1]):
LimitTutor((sqrt(3+x)-sqrt(3-x))/(sqrt(x^2+4)-sqrt(4-2*x)), x = 0);
 $$ finds the limit under consideration step by step with explanations, not using L'Hospital's rule. Your wish came true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{3+x}+\sqrt{3-x}$, also multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{4+x^2}+\sqrt{4-2x}$.

There will be some easy to handle stuff, and also $\dfrac{2x}{x^2+2x}$, which has limit $1$. The final answer should be $\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$.

**Remark:** Whenever $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}$ gets into trouble, its friend $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$ is ready to pitch in and help. Note that $(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})=a-b$.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but I realized I messed it up. Helped a lot . :)

Comment: You are welcome. Multiplying top and bottom by the conjugate is often useful.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when you have a rational expression in the bottom and when you want to calculate the limit, what you have to do is multiply by the conjugate of the denominator. By conjugate, I mean the same expression, but opposite in sign. I believe that you refer to this is as rationalizing the denominator. If you can do this, it will make calculating the limit by hand a little easier. :)